# woocommerce_rest_authentication_error - 410 - Invalid signature

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, woocommerce-rest-api

I am building an Ionic app using woocommerce API

Below is my woocommerce provider .ts file

```
import * as WC from 'woocommerce-api';
this.Woocommerce =  new WC({
        url: "http://myftuplad.com",
        consumerKey: "ok_d064f357304e",
        consumerSecret: "os_0e59869ac5e08",
        wpAPI: true,
        version: 'wc/v2'
        /*queryStringAuth: true,
        verify_ssl: false*/
    });
```

Below is checkout.ts file to place and order

```
this.WooCommerce.postAsync("orders", orderData.order).then((data) => {
    let response = (JSON.parse(data.body));
    console.log(response);
})
```

Below is the error :

```
code : woocommerce_rest_authentication_error 
status : 401
message : Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is sometimes caused by server name resolution, try adding "www." to your url.